# Memory Leak Merging 2 Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, merge, memory-leaks

I am not the first one asking about this issue however my problem seems a bit different from what I saw. Basically I was trying to merge a dataframe `A.shape = [900k, 6]` and `B.shape = [600k, 6]` and I get a memory error with a `pd.merge(A, B, how='left', left_on=[col_1, col_2], right_on=[col_1, col_2])`. (I have 5GB of RAM available for the computation.)

To try to circunvent it, I tried to do it iteratively like below but after the 6 first iterations where the memory computation time increases slightly from one to the other, it explodes at the 7th one:

```
def partial_merge(A, partial_B):
    return pd.merge(A, partial_B, 
                 how='left', 
                 left_on=['col_1','col_2'], 
                 right_on = ['col_1','col_2'])

low_bound = 0
for high_bound in tqdm(range(0, merged_stats.shape[0], 10000)):
    A = partial_merge(A, B.iloc[low_bound:high_bound, :])
    gc.collect()
    low_bound = high_bound
```

Any idea ?
I am reaching the point where I am going to write those 2 dataframes to a database to do the join there.

Comment: What type of merge do you have? If this is a many:many merge then 5 GB of RAM might be enough to hold everything in memory depending upon the duplication. If it's a 1:1 then perhaps just concat?

Comment: On the A dataframe, I can have multiple occurences with the same `['col_1', 'col_2']` while one the B dataframe, I have only one of each. The concat would have otherwise been a good idea that I did not even think of.

Comment: I can addthat I tried to run the join inside an SQLite database, outside of python and got the result in 30sec without any memory explosion. However when I wrote a pure sqlite3 solution doing the same query, I got again the memory error.

Comment: I have noticed a similar thing in my code. Repeating the same merge with different columns makes the memory use grow too fast